# reverse order of date in Excel customized calendar

Tags: excel, vba

I am using custom calendar in Excel that is activated after user double clicks on cell. The problem is with the order of month and date in first 12 days. Month is placed in the first place instead of day (changing date format to dd mmmm yyyy doesn't help) so macro puts 02 May 2020 instead of 05 February 2020.

The problem occurs only when selecting first 12 days in calendar, when clicking on 13-31 calendar puts date in proper format so 05 February 2020. The Excel file is available [here](https://files.fm/u/b2n4hzxr#sign_up). Below yo ucan find the whole code:

```
Dim Buttons() As New clsCmdButton

    Sub Show_Cal()
    'use class module to create commandbutton collection, then show calendar

    Dim iCmdBtns As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control

    iCmdBtns = 0
    For Each ctl In frmCalendar.Controls
      If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton"
        Then
      If ctl.Name < > "CB_Close"
        Then
      iCmdBtns = iCmdBtns + 1
      ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To iCmdBtns)
      Set Buttons(iCmdBtns).CmdBtnGroup = ctl
      End If
      End If
    Next ctl

    frmCalendar.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CB_Close_Click()
        Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lYearsAdd As Long
    Dim lYearStart As Long

    lYearStart = Year(Date) - 10
    lYearsAdd = Year(Date) + 10
    With Me
    For i = 1 To 12
        .CB_Mth.AddItem Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), i, 1), "mmmm")
    Next

    For i = lYearStart To lYearsAdd
        .CB_Yr.AddItem Format(DateSerial(i, 1, 1), "yyyy")
    Next

        .Tag = "Calendar"
        .CB_Mth.ListIndex = Month(Date) - 1
        .CB_Yr.ListIndex = Year(Date) - lYearStart
        .Tag = ""
    End With
    Call Build_Calendar

End Sub

Private Sub CB_Mth_Change()
    If Not Me.Tag = "Calendar"
      Then Build_Calendar
End Sub

Private Sub CB_Yr_Change()
    If Not Me.Tag = "Calendar"
        Then Build_Calendar
End Sub

Sub Build_Calendar()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dTemp As Date
    Dim dTemp2 As Date
    Dim iFirstDay As Integer
    With Me
        .Caption = " " & .CB_Mth.Value & " " & .CB_Yr.Value

    dTemp = CDate("01/" & .CB_Mth.Value & "/" & .CB_Yr.Value)
    iFirstDay = WeekDay(dTemp, vbSunday)
        .Controls("D" & iFirstDay).SetFocus

    For i = 1 To 42
    With.Controls("D" & i)
    dTemp2 = DateAdd("d", (i - iFirstDay), dTemp)
        .Caption = Format(dTemp2, "d")
        .Tag = dTemp2
        .ControlTipText = Format(dTemp2, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    'add dates to the buttons
    If Format(dTemp2, "mmmm") = CB_Mth.Value Then
    If.BackColor < > & H80000016 Then.BackColor = & H80000018
    If Format(Date, "dd mmmm yyyy") = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") Then.SetFocus
        .Font.Bold = True
    Else
    If.BackColor < > & H80000016 Then.BackColor = & H8000000F
        .Font.Bold = False
    End If
        'format the buttons
    End With
    Next
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Intersect(Target, Range("DateEntry")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value < > ""
        Then Exit Sub
        Set rngAC = Target
        g_bForm = True
        frmCalendar.Show_Cal
        rngAC.NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
        rngAC.Value = g_sDate
        rngAC.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: try using `dateserial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem.  But it sounds like something due to a mismatch between your generated date and your windows regional data setting.

Try changing your `g_sDate` declaration to:

```
Public g_sDate As Date
```